# pass array of objects to oracle stored procedure using ODP.Net managed client

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures, odp.net-managed

I have following Employee class in my web API.

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

my web API receives the list of 50 employee records on each request and it needs to update those details in Oracle database.

I followed the same approach of passing array of Integers to Oracle stored procedure and tried the below approach.

Created following type and stored procedure in Oracle.

--base type

```
create or replace  type EMPTEST AS OBJECT
(    
    Name   varchar2(50),    
    City          varchar2(50)
);
```

--package

```
create or replace PACKAGE pkgUDFArray_Test
AS 
type "T_EMPUDF_ARRAY" is table of EMPTEST;  
    PROCEDURE ProcEmpUDFArray_Test(
        Param1 IN T_EMPUDF_ARRAY);
END pkgUDFArray_Test;
```

--package body

```
create or replace  PACKAGE BODY pkgUDFArray_Test
AS
    PROCEDURE ProcEmpUDFArray_Test(
        Param1 IN  T_EMPUDF_ARRAY)
    AS
    BEGIN        
        FORALL indx IN 1..Param1.COUNT
            INSERT INTO Employee(Name,City) 
            VALUES(Param1(indx).Name,Param1(indx).City);       
    END ProcEmpUDFArray_Test;
END pkgUDFArray_Test;
```

Following is the code from web API.

```
     List<Employee> EmpList = new List<Employee>()
    {
        new Employee() { City = "City1", Name="Emp1" },
        new Employee() {City = "City2", Name="Emp2" }
    };            

        OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(connectionString);       

        con.Open();
        var cmd = con.CreateCommand();

        cmd.CommandText = "pkgUDFArray_Test.ProcEmpUDFArray_Test";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        OracleParameter param1 = new OracleParameter();
        param1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;            
        param1.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;
        param1.Value = EmpList.ToArray();
        param1.Size = 2;
        param1.DbType = DbType.Object;

        try
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
```

When i tried this I get the error "value does not fall within the expected range." at the following line.
param1.Value = EmpList.ToArray();

I see that I need to do some more here to get it worked.

I searched for similar topics and I could not find any topics on this for managed client. I know there is a way for this using old Oracle.DataAccess.dll, but wanted to know if there is a way using latest managed client.

Comment: I tried your code, and setting the size before setting the value works well for me :)

Comment: Please take a look at my answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75258742/c-sharp-pass-array-of-objects-udt-to-oracle-stored-procedure-returns-exception . There is a github thread:https://github.com/oracle/dotnet-db-samples/issues/56, where an oracle developer gives examples on how to do this:https://github.com/oracle/dotnet-db-samples/tree/master/samples/udt