# Pass an array of objects in a variable to a stored procedure through Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle-manageddataaccess

With the latest Oracle Managed drivers, there is no support for Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt and OracleDbType.Array
I want to pass an array of integers and retrieve corresponding data from a stored procedure.

```
List<OracleParameter> lstParams = new List<OracleParameter>()
new OracleParameter(){ParameterName = "PARAM1", Value = new Int32[]{1,2,3}, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input, CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray, Size = 3},
new OracleParameter(){ParameterName = "OUT_CUR", Value = null, OracleDbType = OracleDbType.RefCursor, Direction = ParameterDirection.Output}
};

using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand() { CommandText = "MANAGED_DEMO_TEST", Connection = OracleConnectionFactory.GetInstance(), CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure})
{
cmd.Parameters.AddRange(lstParams.ToArray());
//Getting exception at this line
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
}
```

In Oracle, I am creating a custom type and using it in the procedure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE CUSTOM_ID IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
create or replace PROCEDURE MANAGED_DEMO_TEST(
PARAM1 IN CUSTOM_ID,
OUT_CUR out sys_refcursor
) 
AS BEGIN
open out_cur for
--Random select statement to test the execution of SP
SELECT * from my_table where id = 1;
END;
```

Currently I am getting an exception: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'MANAGED_DEMO_TEST'

The main intention is to pass an array of custom type objects to a stored procedure.
I have tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41188587/pass-array-of-objects-to-oracle-stored-procedure-using-odp-net-managed-client), but did not work for me. Got the same exception.

Comment: When you have a procedure with one imput parameter and one output parameter, why are you not using a `FUNCTION`?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Why should you convert all procedures with a single output parameter to a function? Just because function signatures have that pattern does not preclude procedures from also having that signature.

Comment: For me a method with one return value is a function - but maybe this is more a matter of taste.

Comment: This is just a dummy procedure, which I am using for POC purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you must use an "Associative array" rather than a "Nested table".

Instead of

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE CUSTOM_ID IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
```

you have to use

```
TYPE CUSTOM_ID IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
```

However, you cannot create an Associative array as schema objects (i.e. `CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE CUSTOM_ID IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER` does not work). You have to define the Associative array in your Package, perhaps you have to convert it into a nested table if required.